# Loading image in java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to load an image using the following code, but no image comes up only the window is shown...

```
public class loadImg extends Component
{
public Image loadImageFile()
{
    Image i = null;
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    i = tk.getImage("abcd.jpg");
    waitFrImg(i);
    return(i);
}
private void waitFrImg(Image a)
{
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(a, 1);
    try {
        mt.waitForAll();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        //System.exit(1);
        System.out.println("Loading of the image was interrupted" );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And where exactly do you display the image?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 3) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what `MediaTracker` does is tracing the status of a image list. To view the image on the screen either you need to paint it on a component or add it to a component such as a JLabel.

Comment: Thanks, now I have used the paint function to display the image.. and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Using this this `"abcd.jpg"` relative path, without loading from the class, your file structure needs to look something like this (if you're running the program from an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse).

```
ProjectRoot
         adcd.jpg
         src 
         bin
```

Where the IDE will first search for the file in the root directory. This scenario is not good for production though. In a testing environment, it's fine.

---

**NOTE**

As @AndrewThompson noted **"By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an embedded-resource. That being the case, the resource must be accessed by URL instead of File."**. In which case you would want to use `getClass().getResource()` which returns a URL

```
tk.getImage(getClass().getResource("resources/abcd.jpg"));
```

What you would need to is right click on your `src` folder and create new package. Call that package `resources`. Then just copy and paste your image into that package.  The package will get copied into the build

---- To display the image you need to paint it on to the component, say a JPanel and override the `paintComponent` method, something like this

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TestImage extends JPanel{
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 256;
    BufferedImage img;

    public TestImage(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/stack_reverse.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not load image");
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestImage());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your image path.

I test your code with Absolute Path, and it works.

By the way, rewrite the JPanel to suit your needs.

---

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image;

    public MyJPanel() {
    }

    public MyJPanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```